# No cache header in Spring Boot response from RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a typical controller which returns JSON and I need to return `no-cache` header as a part of a response. **Please note at this moment I have no spring security on classpath, however if there is need to make it to work out-of-the-box then I'm fine with this**.

Currently I have implemented this in the following manner:

```
public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> createResponseSpringWay(final T body) {
    org.springframework.http.CacheControl cacheControl = org.springframework.http.CacheControl.noCache();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().cacheControl(cacheControl).body(body);
}
```

Is there any spring boot property that can make it automatically for me? I want to get rid of `ResponseEntity` at all methods.

I've tried the following configuration, but I believe it only applies to static resources, so it doesn't work:

```
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store=true
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.must-revalidate=true
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-cache=true
```